# I want to create buttons dynamically and acces any specific

Tags: php, button, dynamic

I want to show buttons depending on the values from a table. Afterwards I need to access anyone button and act according to the label of buttons. To be more specific, i have a table containing names of subjects, I want to show the buttons each having label of a subject. when user clicks a button (eg: Physics), the screen should display a test (MCQs) of Physics only, and so on:

Below is my code:

```
<button id="subj" onclick="showSubjects()">Start Test </button>
<div id="subjects" style="display: none;">
<form method='POST'>
<?php include_once('connect.php'); 
$query = "select distinct subject from subjects order by subject 
desc ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $subjectname = $row['subject'];?>
        <input type="submit" id = "sub" name="sub" 
            value='<?php echo $subjectname; ?>'> 
     <?php } ?>
</form>
</div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){echo $subjectname; } else {echo 
"Nothing";}
?>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showSubjects(){
document.getElementById("subjects").style.display = "block";}
function showTest(){
document.getElementById("tests").style.display = "block";
} </script>
```

This shows 3 buttons: PHISICS   CHEMISTRY   BIOLOGY

when user clicks any of these buttons it takes it as last button value i.e. BIOLOGY.

How can I amend it so that if user clicks CHEMISTRY it should show "Chemistry button clicked" and so on

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that will change based on the submitted form is the $_POST array. Other variables, like $subject, will be the same whatever the user does; PHP isn't going to guess what you want them to be.

You've already got logic checking if the user pressed *any* button:

```
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){ ... }
```

Determining *which* button they pressed is just a matter of looking at that same variable:

```
echo $_POST['sub'];
```

The same goes for any other form controls you add - the user's selections will end up in $_POST, and it's up to you to read them from there.

It's also worth remembering that the logic for *displaying* the form doesn't need to be in the same place as the logic for *precessing* the submitted form, so the fact that these buttons are generated dynamically doesn't make a difference to how you read the submitted data back. You can't even guarantee that the user used your form at all, they could write their own and submit it to your server, or edit it using their browser's debugging tools.